# Dataset data is updated after inserting into Mysql Database

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, streaming, spark-streaming

I have a small scenario where i read text file and calculate average based on date and store the summary into Mysql database.

Following is code

```
val repo_sum = joined_data.map(SensorReport.generateReport)
          repo_sum.show() --- STEP 1
          repo_sum.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(url, "sensor_report", prop)
          repo_sum.show() --- STEP 2
```

After calculating average in repo_sum dataframe following is the result of STEP 1

```
+----------+------------------+-----+-----+
|      date|               flo|   hz|count|
+----------+------------------+-----+-----+
|2017-10-05|52.887049194476745|10.27|  5.0|
|2017-10-04|  55.4188048943416|10.27|  5.0|
|2017-10-03|  54.1529270444092|10.27| 10.0|
+----------+------------------+-----+-----+
```

Then the save command is executed and the dataset values at step 2 is

```
+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----+
|      date|              flo|                hz|count|
+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----+
|2017-10-05|52.88704919447673|31.578524597238367| 10.0|
|2017-10-04| 55.4188048943416| 32.84440244717079| 10.0|
+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----+
```

Following is complete code

```
class StreamRead extends Serializable {
  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.OuterScopes.addOuterScope(this);
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Application").setMaster("local[2]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2))
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(ssc.sparkContext)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val sensorDStream = ssc.textFileStream("file:///C:/Users/M1026352/Desktop/Spark/StreamData").map(Sensor.parseSensor)
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/streamdata"
    val prop = new java.util.Properties
    prop.setProperty("user", "root")
    prop.setProperty("password", "root")
    val tweets = sensorDStream.foreachRDD {
      rdd =>
        if (rdd.count() != 0) {
          val databaseVal = sqlContext.read.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/streamdata", "sensor_report", prop)
          val rdd_group = rdd.groupBy { x => x.date }
          val repo_data = rdd_group.map { x =>
            val sum_flo = x._2.map { x => x.flo }.reduce(_ + _)
            val sum_hz = x._2.map { x => x.hz }.reduce(_ + _)
            val sum_flo_count = x._2.size
            print(sum_flo_count)
            SensorReport(x._1, sum_flo, sum_hz, sum_flo_count)
          }
          val df = repo_data.toDF()
          val joined_data = df.join(databaseVal, Seq("date"), "fullouter")
          joined_data.show()
          val repo_sum = joined_data.map(SensorReport.generateReport)
          repo_sum.show()
          repo_sum.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(url, "sensor_report", prop)
          repo_sum.show()
        }
    }

    ssc.start()
    WorkerAndTaskExample.main(args)
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
  case class Sensor(resid: String, date: String, time: String, hz: Double, disp: Double, flo: Double, sedPPM: Double, psi: Double, chlPPM: Double)

  object Sensor extends Serializable {
    def parseSensor(str: String): Sensor = {
      val p = str.split(",")
      Sensor(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3).toDouble, p(4).toDouble, p(5).toDouble, p(6).toDouble, p(7).toDouble, p(8).toDouble)
    }
  }
  case class SensorReport(date: String, flo: Double, hz: Double, count: Double)
  object SensorReport extends Serializable {
    def generateReport(row: Row): SensorReport = {
      print(row)
      if (row.get(4) == null) {
        SensorReport(row.getString(0), row.getDouble(1) / row.getDouble(3), row.getDouble(2) / row.getDouble(3), row.getDouble(3))
      } else if (row.get(2) == null) {
        SensorReport(row.getString(0), row.getDouble(4), row.getDouble(5), row.getDouble(6))
      } else {
        val count = row.getDouble(3) + row.getDouble(6)
        val flow_avg_update = (row.getDouble(6) * row.getDouble(4) + row.getDouble(1)) / count
        val flow_flo_update = (row.getDouble(6) * row.getDouble(5) + row.getDouble(1)) / count
        print(count + " : " + flow_avg_update + " : " + flow_flo_update)
        SensorReport(row.getString(0), flow_avg_update, flow_flo_update, count)
      }
    }
  }
```

As far as i understand when save command is executed in spark the whole process runs again, is my understanding is correct please let me know.

Comment: Try to cache the `RDD` and see if it still occurs: `val repo_sum = joined_data.map(SensorReport.generateReport).cache()`.

Comment: Yes val repo_sum = joined_data.map(SensorReport.generateReport).cache() works well

Comment: Added a more complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark all transformations are lazy, nothing will happen until an [action](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) is called. At the same time, this means that if multiple actions are called on the same RDD or dataframe, all computations will be performed multiple times. This includes loading the data and all transformations.

To avoid this, use `cache()` or `persist()` (same thing except that `cache()` can specify different types of storage, the default is RAM memory only). `cache()` will keep the RDD/dataframe in memory after the first time an action was used on it. Hence, avoiding running the same transformations multiple times.

---

In this case, since two actions are performed on the dataframe is causing this  unexpected behavior, caching the dataframe would solve the problem:

```
val repo_sum = joined_data.map(SensorReport.generateReport).cache()
```